# Axis2 / CXF: WSDL-to-Java - Auto generated code compared to original code?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf, apache-axis, generated

I am researching web service development. Below are a few assumptions and questions I have arrived at from looking at various sources.

When someone creates a web service when they exposing methods externally using Axis2?

Given a WSDL file can be generated using the 'Java-to-WSDL' feature. If I was to then reverse that WSDL using the WSDL-to-Java feature, how would the auto-generated Java code compare to the original Java code?

I assume the auto-generated code is just a skeleton structure, i.e. an interface?

Comment: Ok i found the answers to my questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241781/how-does-a-wsimport-generated-client-work