# How do I specify url in JAX-WS call and avoid initial network connection?

Tags: java, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS standard stuff with `wsimport http://localhost/Order.wsdl` to generate client stub classes.

The live web service is on a different host, so I need to supply a url when I make the service call. My approach so far has been like this (classes below are generated from wsimport):

```
 1. OrderService s = new OrderService (
                                       new URL("https://live/WS/Order"), 
                                       new QName(...));
 2. OrderServicePort port = s.getOrderServicePort();

 3. configureHttpCertificatesStuff(port) // Set up ssl stuff with the port

 4. port.placeOrder(args); // The actual ws call
```

*First:* Is this the correct way of specifying the url?

*Second:* It seems the constructor in line 1 actually **makes a network call** to the new URL! This results in an exception (due to https not being configured), so I never get to the next line.

Background: I am implementing two-way ssl auth as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client). This means I need to configure ssl stuff in the `port` before the service call. I can't have the constructor make any connection before I've configured the ssl layer correctly for obvious reasons...

**Update:**

Apparenty the url is to the WSDL, not the endpoint when using jax-ws standard. This tripped me up. Loading the WSDL directly from file solved that problem.

Setting the endpoint url is done like this:

```
BindingProvider b = (BindingProvider) port;        
b.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have your build process arrange for the WSDL file processed by `wsimport` to become a class path resource for your app. There are any number of ways to do this, but lets assume you take a JAR-per-service approach. So, you'd run `Order.wsdl` through `wsimport` and take the resulting classes, like `OrderService` and `OrderServicePort`, and stuff them into `order-service.jar`. The other thing you could do would be to stuff a copy of `Order.wsdl` into that same JAR at `META-INF/wsdl/Order.wsdl`. Assuming that JAR file is then part of the class path for your app, you can get the WSDL's URL by doing:

```
URL wsdlLocation = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/wsdl/Order.wsdl");
```