# web service client : Connection Refused, but service works from SoapUI

Tags: web-services, wsdl, connection, jboss7.x

I have a web service deployed on `Jboss 7.1` Server.
I want to test the service, so have written simple `Java Application`,which calls service methods.
I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

but the `wsdl` loads in `browser` (url is exactly the same) and from `Soap UI` the service is working.

---

I've found this post: https://community.jboss.org/thread/204961?_sscc=t 
and changed `<wsdl-host>` in `standalone.xml` file. 
After this i was able to call web service from my java application, but the weirdest part is that I have another web service deployed on the same `Jboss` and I could connect to it without problems.

I don't get if the "`localhost`" in `wsdl`'s `soap:address location` was an issue, then why did another service work properly ?

Comment: If you are using SSL take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client