# Change keystore and truststore at runtime

Tags: java, web-services, runtime, keystore

I'm working on a client that consumes an https web service (client code created with JAX-WS RI). The server requires users authentication, provided with different PKCS12 files. When my client starts, I set the keystore and the truststore as follows:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",fileKeystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",pwdKeystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","PKCS12");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",fileTruststore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",pwdTruststore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
```

Then I consume the WS, and all works:

```
string result = myClient.WSMethod(...);
```

I know these system properties can't be changed in the same way once setted. So, if I need to change the keystore to consume the webservice, without restart my server, as another user, what should I do?

In other words, I would achieve this behaviour:

1. Consume the WS using keystore/truststore of user #1
2. Consume the WS using keystore/truststore of user #2
3. ....

Searching on SO I read about creating an SSLContext but I'm a little bit confused about how to do that and assign it to the connection with the WS.

Comment: maybe it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client

Comment: Thank you! The link helped me to find a workin solution!

Comment: @user1516873 did you got the solution.. how did you resolved it?

Comment: @Dan if you solved the issue, please provide the answer below

Comment: Would you share your solution? That is what this is for : )