# How to send https soap request through java client?

Tags: java, ssl, soap, https, soap-client

i have a jks and i want to set the keystore and truststore while calling the soap based service.
How can I do it without using System.setproperty?

Comment: You’ll need to create an SSLContext, initialize it with your keystore and truststore, get the context’s SSLSocketFactory, and set that socket factory in the port’s BindingProvider properties.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001102/how-to-programmatically-set-the-sslcontext-of-a-jax-ws-client.

Comment: Do i need to add any external dependency in that case ?

Comment: I assume you’re using JAX-WS, so you already have JAX-WS as a dependency.  Nothing else is needed.